# amending vba code to reduce manual input

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below code to help automate my spreadsheet and once this has run i am using another macro to automatically send emails.
What i am hoping to achieve here is to reduce the user input even further as at present, i need to select a range when requested via the input box, but would like to get this automated by selecting a range that is pre determined within the VBA.

i believe it is the application.inputbox area in which i need to update, but having trawled through other posts, have not been able to find anything that would negate the manual input.

```
Sub JoinCells()

Set xJoinRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Highlight source cells to merge",    Type:=8)
xSource = 0
xSource = xJoinRange.Rows.Count
xType = "rows"
If xSource = 1 Then
    xSource = xJoinRange.Columns.Count
    xType = "columns"
End If
Set xDestination = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Highlight destination cell", Type:=8)    If xType = "rows" Then
    temp = xJoinRange.Rows(1).Value
    For i = 2 To xSource
        temp = temp & " " & xJoinRange.Rows(i).Value
    Next i
Else
    temp = xJoinRange.Columns(1).Value
    For i = 2 To xSource
        temp = temp & " " & xJoinRange.Columns(i).Value
    Next i
End If

xDestination.Value = temp

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe I am not following your needs, but what exactly is the trouble you are having deciding on a selecting a predetermined input range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa139976%28v=office.10%29.aspx).

You can easily set any range you want:

```
Dim xJoinRange as Range, xDestination as Range
xJoinRange = Range("D3:E45")
xDestination = Range("G3:H45")
```

Now this will always act on this range in the current/active worksheet.

If you want to specify a range in a specific worksheet then you need to a `Worksheets()` like this:

```
Dim xJoinRange as Range, xDestination as Range
xJoinRange = Worksheets("myWorksheetName").Range("D3:E45")
xDestination = Worksheets("myWorksheetName").Range("G3:H45")
```